# System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHoxstFactory Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, web-config

what does this error mean? 
**Could not locate Razor Host Factory type: System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHoxstFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35**
How can I correct it.
Could any one help me?

Comment: You haven't provided us enough context to determine when you got htis error; what you were doing before you got this error, or what the problem actually is. All we see is an error message that isn't spelled correctly (there is no 'x' in MvcWebRazorHostFactory).

Comment: sorry for that, it was mistaped :( thank you for your help